# Difference between Functions and Function Pointers as Arguments

Tags: c++, function-pointers

This is a rather simple question that is making me a bit curious. Consider the following code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>

int three()
{
    return 3;
}

void foo(int func(void))
{
    std::cout << func() << std::endl;
}

void bar(int (*func)(void))
{
    std::cout << func() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    foo(three);
    bar(three);
    return 0;
}

// output:
// 3
// 3
```

As you can see, we have two functions that take another function as their only argument. However, the function prototypes for them differ. Mainly, we have `void foo(int func(void))` and `void bar(int (*func)(void))`. At first glance, it looks like `foo` is taking the function itself, and `bar` is taking a pointer to a function.

However, they both produce the exact same results, and have the exact same body, and are called in exactly the same manner.

My question is, is there an actually hidden difference between `foo` and `bar`? Is this simply an optional syntax in C++? Is one of the two cases considered "bad style" in C++?

If my compiler is a contributing factor, I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: It has nothing to do with [tag:visual-studio-2010].

Comment: @overcoder: Removed the tag. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no difference:  the types of `foo` and `bar` are the same:  `int(int(*)())`.

There is no such thing as a function-type parameter:  when a parameter appears with the function type syntax (like `int func(void)`), it is transformed into the corresponding pointer-to-function type (like `int (*func)(void)`).

The transformation is similar to how a parameter declared with array syntax (e.g. `int a[]`) is transformed into the corresponding pointer type (`int* a`).